# How to change the target div for an appendChild javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am using a javascript form validator, and it creates a div for its error messages.  Currently it appends the div to the html body but I would like to change it to append it to a specific div of my choosing.  I am new to .js but have given this a shot anyway with no result.

```
function inlineMsg(target,string,autohide) {
var msg;
var msgcontent;
if(!document.getElementById('msg')) {
lightbox = document.getElementById('TB_window');
msg = document.createElement('div');
msg.id = 'msg';
msgcontent = document.createElement('div');
msgcontent.id = 'msgcontent';
document.body.appendChild(msg);
msg.appendChild(msgcontent);
msg.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
msg.style.opacity = 0;
msg.alpha = 0;
} else {
msg = document.getElementById('msg');
msgcontent = document.getElementById('msgcontent');
}
```

The div being created is the #msg div.  From my un-educated mind it looks like line 10 is doing the appending.  document.body.appendChild(msg)

I created line 5 the lightbox = document.getElementById('TB_window')  which I think (from my limited knowledge) allows me to reference lightbox anywhere in this function.  So my thought on line 10 was to do something like;

```
   document.lightbox.appendChild(msg);
```

thereby appending the msg div into the TB_window div but it isn't working... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the document prefix, so

```
lightbox.appendChild(msg);
```

This will be because lightbox is already referring to a document element, it is in effect saying

```
document.document.getElementById();
```

In the same way ATM Machine means Automatic Teller Machine Machine. (Well that's how I understand it to be anway)

Answer (score 0):

`lightbox` is a variable, not a property of the `document` object:

```
lightbox.appendChild(msg);
```

If you are accessing the element only once, you don't even need the variable:

```
document.getElementById('TB_window').appendChild(msg);
```